# What is the best way to assign a user ID - Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm creating an advert like this

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $advert = PropertyAdvertisement::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($advert);
}
```

What is the best way to attach a user_id on the advert model?

Answer (score 0):

After creating, add a line before the return to give the field to the $`advert` variable (assuming user_id is a fillable field on the `PropertyAdvertisement` model and your request is routed through the Auth middleware):

```
$advert->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
$advert->save();
```

Or if you want less code, add the user_id to the $request object in advance of creation:

```
$request['user_id'] = \Auth::user()->id
```